# Converting DisplayPort to DVI-D

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, dvi

Graphics Card: ATI FirePro V5800 (FireGL) - http://www.amd.com/us/products/workstation/graphics/ati-firepro-3d/v5800/pages/v5800.aspx

Current setup one 17" IPS connected to the DVI port
Two DisplayPort -> DVI converters, they look like DVI-D configuration.  These connect to DVI Single Link cables and then to two monitors.

I'd like to replace the two lower resolution monitors with a high resolution IPS panel ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BUI44US/ref=olp_product_details?ie=UTF8&me=&seller=](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BUI44US)), but it required DVI-D. Will my DisplayPort to DVI adapters work?  I've heard that you can have up to two, but not three for some monitors, in this case I only need two.

Answer (score 1):

Your current adapters will most likely not work. You would need an *Active DisplayPort to Dual-link DVI converter* to make this work. DP can support QHD(2560x1440), but not when connected to passive DP->DVI adapter.

Do not be fooled, an active converter will run you about $100; they are not cheap. These are not the $2 adapters that you get with your graphics card.

Comment: Wow, that sucks. I just bought a "QHD" (2560x1440) HP Pavilion monitor that only has HDMI and DisplayPort outputs, while my computer's current graphics card only has 2 DVI-D connections.